# How do I migrate data from one model to another using South in Django?

Tags: database, django, django-models, data-migration, django-south

I created a Django app that had its own internal voting system and a model called Vote to track it.  I want to refactor the voting system into its own app so I can reuse it.  However, the original app is in production and I need to create a data migration that will take all the Votes and transplant them into the separate app.

How can I get two apps to participate in a migration so that I have access to both their models?  Unfortunately, the original and separate apps both have a model named Vote now, so I need to be aware of any conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [db.rename_table](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/db.rename_table)?

I would start by creating a migration in either the new or old app that looks something like this.

```
class Migration:

    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_table('old_vote', 'new_vote')    

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_table('new_vote', 'old_vote')
```

If that does not work you can migrate each item in a loop with something along these lines:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for old in orm['old.vote'].objects.all():
        # create a new.Vote with old's data
models = {
    'old.vote' = { ... },
    'new.vote' = { ... },
}
```

Note: You must use `orm[...]` to access any models outside the app currently being migrated.  Otherwise, standard `orm.Vote.objects.all()` notation works.

Comment: That's some keen lateral thinking!  I still need to get content IDs and such to convert the ForeignKey to a GenericForeignKey, but I can do that all from the one app.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Your update is much simpler than the one I was going to make.  As a side note, be careful if your models have a ManyToManyField in them.  I think South 0.6.2 is having a hard time  getting them right.